# Android dynamic positioning

Tags: android

Depending on a user's input/cancellation, some EditTexts/Buttons would be visible/invisible.

However, Android does not automatically close/open up the space to after removing/adding items that're anchored to it like in Java Swing... while leaving unanchored items alone.

How do I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

this will not only hide the View but it will also remove the space.

and

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

to make the view visible again.